# Cuts and cycles in graph, edges in common

Tags: graph-theory

If there is a cycle C and a cut set S in a connected graph G then C and S have even number of common edges.

Comment: A **cut** is always a set of edges, that is, we can partition $V(G)$ into vertex sets $V_1$ and $V_2$ with $V(G) = V_1 \cup V_2$. The cut $S$ is the set of edges between $V_1$ and $V_2$ in $G$. What you have to prove ist that every cut and the edge set of every cycle have an even number (including $0$) edges in common.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\delta(X)$ be the cut, where $X\subseteq V(G)$. Let $C$ be a cycle, moreover, we order its vertices, say $C=v_0v_1\dots v_k$, with $v_0=v_k$. For each edge $e=\{v_i,v_{i+1}\}\in \delta(X)\cap C$ with $v_i\in X$ and $v_{i+1}\notin X$, let $\phi(i)$ be the smallest index with $\phi(i)>i$ and $v_{\phi(i)}\notin X$ and $v_{\phi(i)+1}\in X$. Then, it is a one-to-one correspondance: $\{v_i,v_{i+1}\}\leftrightarrow\{v_{\phi(i)},v_{\phi(i)+1}\}$. Hence, $|\delta(X)\cap C|$ is even.

Comment: Because it is a cycle, and we give it a orientation: $v_0v_1\dots v_k$, so just imagine you walk through the vertices one by one, every time you walk through a edge from $X$ to $V(G)\setminus X$, after some time you must then walk from $V(G)\setminus X$ to $X$.